# to run beforemethod before dataprovider

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

We are trying to automate the test cases to run in parallel .For this we are using Testng annotations, like @test ,@before method and @data provider. Problem we are facing is, for all the @test the @before method is running but only for the test having @data provider it is getting run after @dataprovider. That is the problem

Our code looks like this

```
    Class Test()
{
Public  Test()
{
//  code 
}
@Beforemethod
Public BeforeTest(){
//Initializing an object  for a class where all methods in which we are running in the @Test methods
}
@Dataprovider
Public Dataprovider()
{
//code
}
@Aftermethod
Public Aftermethod()
{
Null the object created in the @before method
}
@Test
Public test1(){
//code
}
@Test(groups={"tests_verifyDataEntryScenarios"},enabled=true, dataProvider = “name”)
Public Test2()
{
//code
}
```

Problem  coming with the ‘@Test  test2()’, as it has data provider,  instead of calling before method first it is calling data provider first but the object used in @dataprovider was initialized in the @beforemethod, As the dataprovider calling first for test2 it is throwing Null pointer exception. Is there any way to call the ‘@beforemethod’ before @Dataprovider.

Comment: Since this object is being used in all the tests, you can initialize and destroy in BeforeClass and AfterClass respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,But we have used that annotation,actually on using Before and after class we are unable to run the testcases in parallel, so as per our investigation on tests run in parallel, we should use @Beforemethod